# Is there a quicker way to rowwise sum across selected columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using dplyr to sum rowwise across selected columns in a data frame. Because I'm using a character vector to specify the columns, it seems I need to use `rowwise`, which seems to be very calculation heavy and takes ages across my big data frame (>15 min). Does anyone know of a quicker way please!?

```
x <- data.frame("channel_1" = seq(1, 10),
                "channel_2" = seq(1, 10),
                "channel_3" = seq(1, 10),
                "channel_4" = seq(1, 10),
                "channel_5" = seq(1, 10))

ladder.channel <- "channel_4"
bleed.channels <- setdiff(c("channel_1", "channel_2", "channel_3", "channel_4", "channel_5"), ladder.channel)
  y <- x %>%
    mutate(correction = -pmax(!!!syms(bleed.channels))) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(channel.corr = sum(across(all_of(c(ladder.channel, "correction")))))
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example of `x`?

Comment: Example of x added above as requested

Comment: would `ladder.channel` ever have more than one element?

Comment: No only ever one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```r
x %>%
  mutate(
    correction = -pmax(!!!syms(bleed.channels)),
    channel.corr = !!sym(ladder.channel) + correction
  )
```